# Capture Time Right Down to the Second

Tags: bash

How do I capture the date & time right down to the second and store it in a variable?

Take for example if I wanted Tuesday Dec 8th 2015 1:00:20 pm the output should look like this:

130020-8-12-2015

So far I only have the date:

```
function backup() 
{
    local now="$(date +'%d-%m-%Y')"
    echo $now
}
```

Comment: you may have a special need, but generally a very effective date format is `YYYYMMDD.hhmm`. Then you can do simple comparisons LT, GT =, etc Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out the manpage for `date`. Use command `man date`. You will find in the manpage:

```
%H     hour (00..23)
%I     hour (01..12)
%k     hour ( 0..23)
%l     hour ( 1..12)
%M     minute (00..59)
%N     nanoseconds (000000000..999999999)
%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
%S     second (00..60)
%T     time; same as %H:%M:%S
%z     +hhmm numeric timezone (e.g., -0400)
```

Amongst many other tokens.

So the following should do what you need

```
function backup() 
{
    local now="$(date +'%H%M%S-%d-%m-%Y')"
    echo $now
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`date +'%H%M%S-%d-%m-%Y'` would give you your desired format.

Comment: Don't disregard @JNevill 's answer: it's more important to understand how to fix these problems yourself!